# Web Application deployment with JBoss minimal profile

Tags: jboss

I am beginner for JBoss AS. Now I would like to deploy my web application in 'minimal' profile.

I can start 'minimal' profile but I can't deploy my web application to minimal profile.

So, I added some jboss services in deployers and deploy folders.

> > added  "jbossweb.deployer" under minimal/deployers
> >
> > added "jbossweb.sar" under minimal/deploy
> >
> > added "http-invoker.sar" under minimal/deploy
> >
> > added "ROOT.war" under minimal/deploy....

At that time, I found following errors....

2013-09-16 13:35:59,250 INFO  [org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl] (main) JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221053)] Started in 3s:94ms

2013-09-16 13:44:46,968 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (main) Error installing to Real: name=vfsfile:/D:/JavaEE/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/bato/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/ state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real

org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying: vfsfile:/D:/JavaEE/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/bato/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/

```
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)

at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.deploy(BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.java:136)

at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployerWithInput.deploy(AbstractRealDeployerWithInput.java:125)

at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployerWithInput.internalDeploy(AbstractRealDeployerWithInput.java:102)

at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractComponentDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractComponentDeployer.java:78)

at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)

at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)

at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)

at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)

at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)

at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)

at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)

at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)

at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)

at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)

at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)

at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)

at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)

at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)

at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)

at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exception loading class for ScopeKey addition.

```
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.addBeanComponent(BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.java:67)

at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.deploy(BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.java:126)

... 34 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.web.deployers.WARStructure from BaseClassLoader@10f243b{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@113c817{name=vfsfile:/D:/JavaEE/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/bato/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/ domain=ClassLoaderDomain@92668c{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=org.jboss.bootstrap.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@1f934ad} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@28664226[path= context=vfsmemory://a184f-rb8wnb-hlncy1k5-1-hlncy3i0-8 real=vfsmemory://a184f-rb8wnb-hlncy1k5-1-hlncy3i0-8], FileHandler@18670846[path=jbossweb.deployer context=file:/D:/JavaEE/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/bato/deployers/ real=file:/D:/JavaEE/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/bato/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/], DelegatingHandler@33426790[path=jbossweb.deployer/jboss-web-deployer.jar context=file:/D:/JavaEE/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/bato/deployers/ real=file:/D:/JavaEE/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/bato/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/jboss-web-deployer.jar]]  delegates=null exported=[, org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers, META-INF] NON_EMPTY}}

```
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:448)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)

at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.addBeanComponent(BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.java:63)

... 35 more
```

2013-09-16 13:44:47,218 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (main) Error installing to Real: name=vfsfile:/D:/JavaEE/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/bato/deploy/jbossweb.sar/ state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real

org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying: vfsfile:/D:/JavaEE/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/bato/deploy/jbossweb.sar/

```
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)

at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.deploy(BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.java:136)

at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployerWithInput.deploy(AbstractRealDeployerWithInput.java:125)

at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployerWithInput.internalDeploy(AbstractRealDeployerWithInput.java:102)

at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractComponentDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractComponentDeployer.java:78)

at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)

at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)

at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)

at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)

at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)

at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)

at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)

at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)

at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)

at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)

at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)

at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)

at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)

at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)

at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)

at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)

at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/web/tomcat/service/deployers/TomcatDeployerMBean

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:63)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:572)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:532)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:530)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:507)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:134)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:131)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:452)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:251)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:150)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:265)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1119)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:798)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:441)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:63)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:572)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:532)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:530)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:507)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:134)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:131)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:452)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:251)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:150)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:265)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1119)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:798)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:441)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)

at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.addBeanComponent(BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.java:63)

at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.deploy(BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.java:126)

... 34 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployerMBean

```
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)

at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)

at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:292)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1119)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:798)

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:441)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)

... 73 more
```

2013-09-16 13:44:47,250 ERROR [org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap] (main) Failed to load profile: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:

Deployment "jboss:readonly=true,service=invoker,target=Naming,type=http" is missing the following dependencies:

```
Dependency "ServiceBindingManager" (should be in state "Configured", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'ServiceBindingManager' **")
```

Deployment "jboss:service=invoker,target=Naming,type=http" is missing the following dependencies:

```
Dependency "ServiceBindingManager" (should be in state "Configured", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'ServiceBindingManager' **")
```

Deployment "jboss:service=invoker,type=http" is missing the following dependencies:

```
Dependency "ServiceBindingManager" (should be in state "Configured", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'ServiceBindingManager' **")
```

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:

Deployment "vfsfile:/D:/JavaEE/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/bato/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.web.deployers.WARStructure from BaseClassLoader@10f243b{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@113c817{name=vfsfile:/D:/JavaEE/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/bato/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/ domain=ClassLoaderDomain@92668c{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=org.jboss.bootstrap.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@1f934ad} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@28664226[path= context=vfsmemory://a184f-rb8wnb-hlncy1k5-1-hlncy3i0-8 real=vfsmemory://a184f-rb8wnb-hlncy1k5-1-hlncy3i0-8], FileHandler@18670846[path=jbossweb.deployer context=file:/D:/JavaEE/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/bato/deployers/ real=file:/D:/JavaEE/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/bato/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/], DelegatingHandler@33426790[path=jbossweb.deployer/jboss-web-deployer.jar context=file:/D:/JavaEE/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/bato/deployers/ real=file:/D:/JavaEE/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/bato/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/jboss-web-deployer.jar]]  delegates=null exported=[, org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers, META-INF] NON_EMPTY}}

Deployment "vfsfile:/D:/JavaEE/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/bato/deploy/jbossweb.sar/" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployerMBean

Deployment "ServiceBindingManager" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'ServiceBindingManager' **

2013-09-16 13:44:47,250 INFO  [org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl] (main) JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221053)] Started in 3s:16ms

May I know your suggestions and ideas.